# Get file properties from a Item Created/Modified trigger

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a flow that will copy a file from a library to another library dependant on a field value. I have added a On Item Created/Modified trigger but it dosent seem to provide ID for the item added/modified. What is the correct approach for getting this (see dnymaic properties are empty)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Get File Metadata" step before getting the file properties as shown below and then check the field value from the "Get file properties" step

[image]

It is always better to use the metadata step for the SharePoint triggers

Comment: Thanks. Highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you use as identifier in the get file metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing a lot of testing now, and AFAIK this is not possible. However you can achieve the same by using a Property only trigger and then add a Get Content action. Its kind of the opposite, but gives same result.